# selecting consecutive numbers using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a theater seats booking plan.

```
Seat No Status
1 Booked
2 Available
3 Available
4 Available
5 Available
6 Available
7 Booked
8 Available
9 Available
10 Available
```

If someone wants to book 6 tickets, he will get Seat No. 2 to 6 and seat No. 8
And if someone wants to book only 5 tickets, he will get Seat No. 2 to 6

How do I know using SQL query (or PHP code) if the adjacent seats available are more than the seats requested?

Sequential seat selection is the primary goal that I need to achieve.

Comment: Upto 80 seats are allowed at a time

Comment: If someone requests 3 seats, do you want to give them seats 8-10 (keeping 2-6 for someone who wants a larger sequence), or give them any three consecutive seats?

Comment: I want to give 3 seats from 2 to 6. The front rows are preferred by the customers and the seats are allocated on "first come" basis.

Comment: The reservations might get canceled and the status becomes "available" in such cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select seat, status
from seats
where seat >= (
   select a.seat
   from seats a
      left join seats b on 
         a.seat < b.seat and
         b.seat < a.seat + 4 and
         b.status = 'Available'
   where a.status = 'Available'
   group by a.seat
   having count(b.seat)+1 = 4
   )
limit 4
```

This is set to select four consecutive seats.  Adjust all instances of "4" to the desired number of seats to get what you want.

Comment: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row But the subquery runs fine and that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One pass. Put you number in place of `?`. Gives you the number of the seat in the first sequence, when your requirement was met, or `NULL` if no sequence found.

```
SET @FOUND = 0;
SET @SEAT_MATCHED = NULL;

SELECT
    IF(@FOUND < ?,
        @FOUND := IF(status == 'Booked', 0, @FROM + 1),
        @SEAT_MATCHED := IFNULL(@SEAT_MATCHED, seat_no)
    )
FROM seats
ORDER BY seat_no

SELECT @SEAT_MATCHED;
```

More reading: [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html), [User Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

**NB!** This approach is only applicable if there are few records in the analyzed interval!

**Update.** Perhaps you can store bitmask of booked seats in the row as an integer. For instance, for 16-seats row the number `36884` (`1001000000010100` in binary) means *3rd, 5th, 13th and 16th seats are booked*. It would cut down MySQL load. And then you could do the code like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// data you get from DB
$seats = bindec('1001000000010100');
$num_seats = 16;

// calculate consecutive free seats
$seats_info = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_seats; $i++, $seats >>= 1) {
    if ($seats & 1) {
        if (isset($first)) {
            $seats_info[$first] = $i - $first;
            unset($first);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!isset($first)) {
            $first = $i;
        }
    }
}

// output sequences
var_export($seats_info);

?>
```

This outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 2,
  3 => 1,
  5 => 7,
  13 => 2,
)
```

`0` is the *1st* seat.

Comment: in other words it would not give you back anything if the seats arent next to each other? like if 6 seats requested, bt only 5 are in the group and the last one could be taken from the next group you'd still get NULL?

Comment: Yes. But it's more than shantanuo asked. If you like, this query can be slightly modified to meet your requirement as well.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to represent Booked/Available as binary numbers (e.g. 1-free, 0-booked). If you do so, you can elegantly make use of aggregate functions:

```
  select seat as n from seats where
      $num_seats = (select sum(status) from seats
         where seat between n and n + $num_seats - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.seat_no     SEAT1,
       a.seat_no + 1 SEAT2,
       a.seat_no + 2 SEAT3  
  FROM theater a
 WHERE a.availability = 'Y'
   AND seat_no + 1 = (SELECT b.seat_no 
                        FROM theater b 
                       WHERE b.seat_no = a.seat_no + 1 
                         and b.availability = 'Y')
   AND seat_no + 2 = (SELECT b.seat_no 
                        FROM theater b 
                       WHERE b.seat_no = a.seat_no + 2 
                         and b.availability = 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct S2.seat
from (
   select a.seat
   from seats a
      left join seats b on 
         a.seat <= b.seat and
         a.seat + 3 >= b.seat and
         a.availability = 1 and b.availability = 1
   group by a.seat
   having count(b.seat) = 4
   ) as S1
   join 
   seats as S2
   on 
   S1.seat <= S2.seat and S1.seat+3 >= S2.seat
order by S2.seat_no
limit 4;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest one recursive algorithm using SQL and PHP. You need X seats.

1. Select all Available seats using SQL query, you receive N available seats (If N < X, error)
2. In php analyze the results and store them using the adjacent seats groups sizes as a key (there could be more than one group with the same size)

   > '5' => ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
   >
   > '2' => ( 8, 9 )
3. Try to find the group with X seats
4. If not found, pick the closest group with size > X ( for X = 4 it's group '5' )
5. If no bigger groups found, take out the biggest available (group with size Y), then repeat steps 3 - 5 with X = X - Y

Answer (score -3):

**Edit:** Since i have misunderstood the questions here an SQL statement that will return all the **first free seat and the count of adjacent** seats from the first free. The bigger counts of free seats come first.

```
SELECT count(1) free,(
 CASE status
  WHEN "Booked" THEN
   @prev:=NULL
  ELSE
   @prev:=COALESCE(cast(@prev as unsigned), seat_no)
  END) first
FROM 
 (SELECT @prev:=null) f,
 (SELECT seat_no, status FROM seats ORDER BY seat_no) seats
GROUP BY first
HAVING first>=0
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2
```

So for your example it will return:

```
free | first
-----------
   5    2
   3    8
```

If you are only interested in the first sequencial seat that can fit your request and no more just add a condition on the free seat count, so if you want 3 seats adding `free>=3` will do it :

```
SELECT count(1) free,(
 CASE status
  WHEN "Booked" THEN
   @prev:=NULL
  ELSE
   @prev:=COALESCE(cast(@prev as unsigned), seat_no)
  END) first
FROM 
 (SELECT @prev:=null) f,
 (SELECT seat_no, status FROM seats ORDER BY seat_no) seats
GROUP BY first
HAVING first>0 AND free>=3
LIMIT 1
```

this will output:

```
free | first
------------
   5    2
```

Comment: well, that'll give first available seats, and not only adjacent ones. for example 0101010111 and i request 3 seats, your select would give me the ones that are separated and i actually want the last 3 that are next to each other

Comment: Yes i know that, in his example if it request 6 seats it choose also the 8th which is not in the sequence since the 7th is booked, so this answers to what he want no ?

Comment: your result matches his requirement simply because his example is setup in that way. if he had the following layout as his exmaple: 0101010111111110 your select would not match what he'd want, which would be the last 8 seats

Comment: It s not specify in his question how can i guess what he want ?
And if you have only 1/2 seat free what is the expected result ?
What are the rule ?

Comment: "Sequential seat selection is the primary goal that I need to achieve."

Comment: "Sequential seat selection is the primary goal that I need to achieve."