# Selecting Consecutive String Entries with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

At first you might think this is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293856/selecting-consecutive-entries-with-linq-to-entities) question but hopefully you will see it is not.

I also want to select groups of rows that are consecutive but consider that this time the entries are telephone numbers, therefore, stored as string.

I have been trying somethink like:

```
var numbers = await (from a in context.Telephones
                     from b in context.Telephones
                     Convert.ToInt32(a.Number) < Convert.ToInt32(b.Number) &&
                     Convert.ToInt32(b.Number) < (Convert.ToInt32(a.Number) + numberQuantity)
                     group b by new { a.Number }
                         into myGroup
                         where myGroup.Count() + 1 == numberQuantity
                         select myGroup.Key.Number).ToListAsync();
```

But this fails with:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)'` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

I understand that LINQ to Entities does not support `Convert.ToInt32` but I am running out of ideas here to make it work.

So if my database has:

```
2063717608
2063717609
2063717610
2063717611
2063717613
2063717614
```

How can I select consecutive rows based on the string values? And when querying for 3 consecutive numbers get results like:

- From 2063717608 to 2063717610
- From 2063717609 to 2063717611

Comment: Have you tried pulling the range of data you need first from your context, using ToList(), and then doing your group by on the List<Telephones> object?  If you pull them out by forcing ToList() first, you should be outside the limitations of Linq to Entities and you'll expressly be using System.Linq for your expressions, which has a wider net on what you are allowed to do.

Comment: I will try to do that

Comment: You will be successful.  Let me know, and I'll add it as an answer. : )  I can always use the reputation.

Comment: @SlackShot if you try hard, you just need 1 month to get reputation of `15K`, but of course must **try hard** :)))

Comment: @douglaslps you said `querying for 3 consecutive numbers` but I can see there are 4 numbers here: `2063717608 - 2063717609
 - 2063717610 - 2063717611`, so which of them are the 3 consecutive ones?

Comment: Those are two groups of resuls. One from 2063717608 through 2063717610 and other starting on 2063717609 finishing on 2063717611. I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: It's 3. That's what the + numberQuantity is doing in the expression.  I'm assuming his code is in a method, and the "+ numberQuantity" is a method parameter.  It's 2 groups with a 3 number span in the result set.

Comment: @KingKing I spend a little time per day to pop on when I can and help people out.  Sometimes on the weekend, sometimes during the week.  I feel it's an obligation, with how many times I've used the site to solve my own problems. It obviously can't be a full-time career though. Heh. : )

Comment: @SlackShot I don't think creating a List out from the results will help since I would have to loop the list multiple times to perform updates I didn't mention in the question. Probably the performance will be degraded. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @douglasslps Well, if you can't pop out into a list, your question is unanswerable by Linq. The SQLFunctions mentioned by Alireza only convert number types to string.  Not the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- If you are aware of performance side effect of calling `AsEnumerable()` cast your query and do conversion in memory on the retrieved entities.

2- If you don't want solution #1, you have to look for a way to solve the conversion problem:

2-1- Either change the column type in the database to int

2-2- Or select one of the solution previously proposed by other developers such as:

[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: I would avoid 1 because of the performance problems you mentioned.
Option 2.1 is not possible and 2.2 I believe lists solutions to convert int to string while I need to convert strings to int and couldn't find a similar way of doing it on the link you mentioned. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: By 2-2 I mean you should search and there is no straight forward solution for it. As far as I understand so far the only way is to make a Sql function and calling it in your Linq query.

Comment: @Alireza, SQLFunctions won't work, but I think your answer should be accepted.  You do state the only options he has.  In memory processing via ToList(), or changing the type.  My question would be, more about why he is doing this.. is this for reporting purposes? If it is reporting, why aren't you using pure SQL via Telerik or some other reporting tool?

Comment: @SlackShot SqlFunctions in C# doesn't have anything helpful but defining a function in the DB to convert the nvarchar to int and calling it in Linq query definitely works. About the purpose you can comment beneath the question.

Comment: I believe Alireza is right. Anyway I took SlackShot suggestion and I'm parsing the list after it was returned by the linq query.